# Question related to Indian Passport renewal in USA

Tags: indian-citizens, passport

I am planning to renew my Indian passport as it is going to expire with in a year. The passport section asking to provide 2 friends are relatives address and phone numbers. From the below list who are considered as valid relatives.

Parents who are sharing same as my permanent address
Brothers  and sisters
In laws and Co-brothers
Maternal and Peternal uncle and aunt

Comment: Did you mean to say they are asking for "2 friends **or** relatives"? If so, then I'm not sure what the problem is. A relative is somebody related to you. A friend can be anybody. They're looking for two people who know you personally. If somebody is too distantly related to be considered a "relative", then call them a "friend" instead. It shouldn't matter what the definition of "valid relative" is.

Comment: @GregHewgill it's also a bit odd that parents only count if they share the same permanent address.

Answer (score 1):

All of those listed are related to you, either directly (parents, brothers, sisters, aunts and uncles) or through marriage (in-laws, co-brothers). As you're asked to include two, you can choose any or both from the list. You're also allowed to provide name(s) of close acquaintances or friends.

These individuals serve as references, and you're meant to list those who live in the same place in India as you do, since the local authorities use them to verify your details.